# Exclude nested field from encryption Mongoose encryption

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So i am using an npm package called [mongoose-encryption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption) all is great except one important thing. I have an array called reports and it has alot of objects in it. Each object has one unique field called `report_id` the thing is i need to perform a delete operation based on that ID but if i encrypt it mongoose apparently cant find it. For that i excluded some fields like the docs said but i cant apparently exclude a nested field i tried this:

`usersSchema.plugin(encrypt,{secret:sigKey,excludeFromEncryption: ['username','reports.report_id']});`

So the username is excluded from encryption but not the `reports.report_id` 
any ideas?

Comment: Can you add usersSchema code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption] says:

> To encrypt, the relevant fields are removed from the document, converted to JSON, enciphered in Buffer format with the IV and plugin version prepended, and inserted into the _ct field of the document. Mongoose converts the _ct field to Binary when sending to mongo.

If the `reports` field is encrypted by mongoose-encryption, it will not be present at all in the document stored in MongoDB.

If you need the value of the `reports.report_id` field to be accessible in a query while encrypting the `reports` field, you'll need to copy them out to an array that is not being encrypted.

Comment: like i need it to make sure i can delete stuff from the array. but if exclude the array then its pointless. any other suggestions? my goal is to simply encrypt stuff while i put it in db whatever way it might be.

Comment: You won't be able to use any update, match, find, etc. that the server would normally process on an encrypted field.  You could hash the report_id and store the hashes in an array that is not encrypted.  That way you could identify documents that contain a specific report_id, but you would still need to pull the entire document back to the client to modify the array of reports.  Any field that is encrypted is removed from the document, so you can't query on any subfield of the encrypted field `reports` because there is no `reports` field at all in the document that is stored in mongod.

Comment: is there any other encryption solution you can think of? like i said all i want is encryption it doesn't necessarily have to be mongoose-encryption

Comment: [Client side field encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/#client-side-field-level-encryption) is available in MongoDB 4.2, but even that doesn't permit querying fields of an encrypted sub-document.  Basically, anything you want to query on will need to be elevated to a top-level document, or stored in another sub-document that is not encrypted.  You could used one-way hashing to obfuscate the elevated data while maintaining the ability to use equality match.